# Sliding activity from right to left like menu slider android

Tags: android, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I have a source code to do (Slider menu).. 
But I want to do like it to just open a specific content, meaning that I want the second content to appear over the current content from right to left by pressing a button.

Hint: I'm not want to open activity totally by

```
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2);
```

I just want the second content opens over the current content like what sliding menu acts.
(sliding menu appears from left to right by moving my finger from left to right, I want my second content opens from right to left and appears partially by pressing a button and back to hide my passing my fingers over it and move from left to right)

example: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wunderkinder.wunderlistandroid

Sorry if I could not explain, and hope anyone got my mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the "Activity" concept wrong. 
I understand, you can never show 2 activities at the same time. An activity is not a "screen", "view" or something like that... it is a context itself. It covers a whole state in your application. If you want to do something like a slider, you can play with views, animations or even better, fragments.

Comment: OK I just can't explain what I want to do, if you got my mean. could you help me with source code. I edited my question to be clear.

Comment: I think wunderlist is using the slidingmenu library:

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu